# Getting Error: Unknown property searchRes

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I know this error actually comes when the property is not actually defined in controller / when no public access specifier / not getters and setters. But i have given all things still i am getting this

visual force page tag on visualforce page component

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!ShowShareableLink}" 
 oncomplete="shareContentJSWithoutEmail{!sectionName}('{!searchRes.id}',this);"   
 reRender="showShareLink,showAddtoUser,notShowImage,showSLink,shareableLink,showShareLink" 
 style="border-style: initial;width: 113%;background: #e6e6e6;margin-top: 4px;font-weight: normal; margin-left: -10px; height: 34px;"  
  value="Get Shareable Link" status="loaderStatus">
```

this command button is actually passing a parameter from

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allsearches}" var="searchRes">
```

but the weird thing is when i use onclick in command button everything is working fine but when i use oncomplete getting unknown property.

Class level code:

In controller:

```
public list<OpportunityRecommendationsCtrl.Searches> allsearches     {get;set;}
```

service class ctrl:

```
global with sharing class OpportunityRecommendationsCtrl {

        public class Searches {
        public String id {get; set;}
        public String title {get; set;}
        public String description {get; set;}
        public String article_type {get; set;}
        public String state {get; set;}
        public List<String> tags {get; set;}
        public List<String> categories {get; set;}
        public Double rating {get; set;}
        public String publisher_id {get; set;}
        public String publisher_name {get; set;}
        public String published_at {get; set;}
        //public Object expires_at {get; set;}
        public List<String> group_names {get; set;}
        public String file {get; set;}
        public Integer rating_count {get; set;}
        public User_rating user_rating {get; set;}
        public Integer step_count {get; set;}
        public Enrollment enrollment {get; set;}
        public Datetime created_at {get; set;}
        public Datetime updated_at {get; set;}
        public String content_updated_at {get; set;}
        public Boolean is_updated {get; set;}
        public Boolean is_content_updated {get; set;}
        public List<Downloads> downloads {get; set;}
        public Boolean editable {get; set;}
        public Boolean allow_sharing {get; set;}
        public Boolean allow_guest_sharing {get; set;}
        public Image image {get; set;}
        public Boolean isFavorited {get;set;}
        public Boolean allow_download {get;set;}
    }


}
```

This question is actually related to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113103/values-are-not-updating-immediately-on-visual-force-after-command-button-actions?noredirect=1#comment157623_113103

Comment: Does it tell you which property is undefined?

Comment: @AdrianLarson hi i have updated my question thank's, it is searchRes variable

Comment: `searchRes` does not exist in your controller but is rather a variable introduced by your Visualforce `apex:repeat`.

Comment: is the `commandButton` within the `apex:repeat` scope?  That is, there is a commandButton for every iteration of repeat?